# Integration with disk method on shifted access

Tags: integration, volume

I'm learning the disk method in integral calculus, and I'm having trouble understanding something that seems like it should be pretty basic.

For the curve $x^3$ rotated around $y=1$, I'm told that the radius of the disk is $r(x) = 1-x^3$

They give this diagram:
[image: diagram of example of disk method]

However, I thought a vertical translation of the curve would put it at $x^3-1$.

Wouldn't computing the curve this way change the problem? Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: The area is $\pi r^2$, so it does not matter if you have the radius $1-x^3$ or $x^3-1$

Comment: Since the upper boundary of the region to be revolved is $y=1$, the right boundary of this region is $x = 1$.  Note that for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $(x^3 - 1) \leq 0$, so the (non-negative) expression for the radius, for this region, is in fact $1 - x^3.$